# List all the numbers which have an inverse MOD 20

Tags: modular-arithmetic, cryptography

Please help! I’m not sure where to start. I really need someone to thoroughly explain how to do this.

Comment: Hint: In $\mathbb{Z}$ mod $p$, the element $[x]$ has an inverse if and only if $\gcd(x,p) = 1$. Which elements have that property mod $20$?

Comment: By the linked dupes $\,a\,$ is invertible $\bmod 20\iff \gcd(a,20)=1\iff \gcd(a,2)=1=\gcd(a,5),\, $ i.,e. $\,a\,$ is odd and not a multiple of $5\ \ $

Answer (score 0):

Let $a\in\{1,3,7,9,11,13,17,19\}$.  For each of these, there exist $x,y$ such that $xa+20y=1$, by Bezout.  That says that $xa\cong1\bmod{20}$.  In other words, $x\cong
a^{-1}\bmod{20}$.

As a check, $\varphi(20)=8$.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

$$20=2^2.5$$

$$\phi(20)=20(1-\frac 12)(1-\frac 15)=8$$

So, there are $ 8 $  inversible elements in $ \Bbb Z/20\Bbb Z$.